# JOIN when no data exists

Tags: sql, join, db2

Disclaimer: *I don't have a lot of tech background and just learning SQL so apologies.*
I have 2 table for acct information - one ref data (ACCT_RD) and one txn data (ACCT_TD).

ACCT_RD is like this

| ACCT_ID | ACCT_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | xyz |

ACCT_TD is like this

| ACCT_ID | DATE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-31-2020 | 4000.33 |
| 1 | 01-31-2021 | 2000.11 |
| 2 | 01-31-2020 | 5666.23 |

I want a query where I will pass the account id and date and it will return me data in format

| ACCT_ID | NAME | DATE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 01-31-2020 | 4000.33 |
| 1 | abc | null | null |

it could be that the ACCT_TD may not contain data (no rows) for all dates but ACCT_RD will always have the info.

I am trying a LEFT Join like

```
SELECT R.ACCT_ID, R.NAME, T.VALUE, T.DATE
FROM ACCT_RD R
    LEFT JOIN ACCT_TD T ON R.ACCT_ID = T.ACCT_ID
WHERE R.ACCT_ID = 1
  AND T.DATE IN ('01-31-2000','01-31-2020')
```

I am getting a row where I have data in both and no row where I don't have data in ACCT_TD.

Is it because in ACCT_TD no row exists for date '01-31-2000' and it is not a column for ACCT_RD?

How can I achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the following requirements for the result set.

- For any given `ACCT_ID` It must contain all the corresponding rows
  (if any) from `ACCT_TD`
- VALUE and DATE result set columns are equal to `ACCT_TD.VALUE` and `ACCT_TD.DATE`, if `ACCT_TD.DATE` is in a list of date parameters passed, and both NULL otherwise

If it's the correct understanding of requirements, then try this:

```
WITH 
  ACCT_RD (ACCT_ID, ACCT_NAME) AS
(
VALUES
  (1, 'abc')
, (2, 'xyz')
)
, ACCT_TD (ACCT_ID, DATE, VALUE) AS
(
VALUES
  (1, '01-31-2020', 4000.33)
, (1, '01-31-2021', 2000.11)
, (2, '01-31-2020', 5666.23)
)
SELECT 
  R.ACCT_ID, R.ACCT_NAME
, CASE WHEN T.DATE IN ('01-31-2000','01-31-2020') THEN T.DATE  END AS DATE
, CASE WHEN T.DATE IN ('01-31-2000','01-31-2020') THEN T.VALUE END AS VALUE
FROM ACCT_RD R
LEFT JOIN ACCT_TD T ON R.ACCT_ID = T.ACCT_ID
WHERE R.ACCT_ID = 1;
```

The result is:

```
|ACCT_ID|ACCT_NAME|DATE      |VALUE  |
|-------|---------|----------|-------|
|1      |abc      |01-31-2020|4000.33|
|1      |abc      |          |       |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to guarantee that one row is returned even when there is no match in the second table, just move the date filters to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT R.ACCT_ID, R.NAME, T.VALUE, T.DATE
FROM ACCT_RD R LEFT JOIN
     ACCT_TD T
     ON R.ACCT_ID = T.ACCT_ID AND
        T.DATE IN ('01-31-2000', '01-31-2020')
WHERE R.ACCT_ID = 1;
```

The values will be `NULL` if there is no match.

Also, if your columns are really dates, then you should use proper date formats:

```
        T.DATE IN ('2000-01-31', '2000-01-31')
```